# How to send PaintEvent in wxpython

Tags: wxpython

I'm trying to generate a PaintEvent in wxpython to trigger redrawing a window. However, I can't seem to make it work, I get errors because I try to use a PaintDC outside of a native paint event.

Here is a minimal example:

```
import wx

class AppFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AppFrame, self).__init__(parent=None, title="Demo")
        self.SetClientSize((800,600))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.paint)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.onclick)

    def onclick(self, event):
        wx.PostEvent(self,wx.PaintEvent())

    def paint(self, event=None):
        print "paint"
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(wx.BLACK, 4))
        dc.DrawLine(0, 0, 50, 50)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(redirect=False)
    appFrame = AppFrame()
    appFrame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I know I could call Refresh() in the onclick handler to get the same functionality (and use CallAfter to make it threadsafe), but I would like to understand why I can't send PaintEvents.

I'm on Mac OS 10.7 with wxpython 3.0.1.1, Python 2.7.1. The error I get is

```
  File "test.py", line 17, in paint
    dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/wxPython-3.0.0.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-osx_cocoa/wx/_gdi.py", line 5122, in __init__
    _gdi_.PaintDC_swiginit(self,_gdi_.new_PaintDC(*args, **kwargs))
wx._core.PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "window->MacGetCGContextRef() != NULL" failed at /BUILD/wxPython-src-3.0.0.0/src/osx/carbon/dcclient.cpp(195) in wxPaintDCImpl(): using wxPaintDC without being in a native paint event
```

Comment: Your example works as expected on wxPython 2.9.5/Python 2.7.6 32 bit on Win7 32 bit (handling EVT_PAINT on click). Are you on a different platform?

Comment: Yes, I'm on Mac OS with wxpython 3. I edited my question.

Comment: Tested also on wxPython 3.0.0.0 msw (classic), no issues here. Would be interesting what the difference betreen a "native" and non-"native paint event" should be...

Answer (score 3):

Calling the window's `Refresh` method will trigger a paint event, by marking the window or a subrectangle of it as "damaged".  The system will then send a paint event as soon as it can, with all of the "damaged" regions added together in the event's update region.  If you want the paint event to happen immediately instead of waiting for the system you can then call the window's `Update` method, however usually the right thing to do is to just wait for the system to send it naturally.

Comment: So I'm not supposed to send PaintEvents at all? The documentation doesn't say anything about this.

Comment: Interestingly replacing everything in `self.onclick` with `self.Update()` (instead of `self.Refresh()` as proposed, no Paint events are generated by clicking.

Comment: **> So I'm not supposed to send PaintEvents at all?** Yes and no.  You should always let the system send the paint events because there is some platform specific housekeeping that needs to be done to make it work. OTOH, `Refresh` is the mechanism you can use to ask the system to send the event.

Comment: **Update vs. Refresh**  You can look at it this way: The `Refresh` method asks the system to add the specified rectangle (or the whole window) to the update region passed with the next regularly scheduled paint event.  The `Update` method says, "send any pending paint events right now."  So, unless there is already a pending paint event, calling just `Update` without a prior `Refresh` does not do anything.