# Issue with Paint Event on Mac OSX 10.8.5 in wxPython

Tags: python, macos, wxpython, paint, paintevent

In my program I have an image (bitmap) loaded into a wxScrolledWindow. I'm trying to draw a grid over the image but I just cannot get it to work. My job is to port this program over from Windows, which it was originally developed on, and make it work on Mac as well but it is a bigger pain the butt than I expected.

```
def OnPaint(self, event):
    dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self.staticBitmap,self.staticBitmap.GetBitmap())
    dc.Clear()
    dc.DrawBitmap(self.wxBitmap, 0, 0)    
    self.drawGrid(dc)
    event.Skip()

def drawGrid(self, dc):
    gridWid, gridHgt = self.staticBitmap.GetBitmap().GetSize()
    numRows, numCols = self.gridSize, self.gridSize
    if self.controlPanel.showGridBox.IsChecked():
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(self.gridColor, self.gridThickness))
        dc.SetTextForeground(self.gridColor)
        cellWid = float( gridWid - 1) / numRows
        cellHgt = float( gridHgt - 1) / numCols
        for rowNum in xrange( numRows + 1) :
            dc.DrawLine( 0, rowNum*cellHgt, gridWid, rowNum*cellHgt )
        for colNum in xrange( numCols + 1 ) :
            dc.DrawLine( colNum*cellWid, 0, colNum*cellWid, gridHgt )
```

This code works just fine on Windows 7, but I keep getting this error when running it on Mac:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/kyra/Documents/workspace/ADAPT/src/GUI.py", line 1617, in OnPaint
dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self.staticBitmap, self.staticBitmap.GetBitmap())
File "/usr/local/lib/wxPython-3.0.2.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-osx_cocoa/wx/_gdi.py", line 5290, in __init__
_gdi_.BufferedPaintDC_swiginit(self,_gdi_.new_BufferedPaintDC(*args, **kwargs))
wx._core.PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "window->MacGetCGContextRef() != NULL" failed at /BUILD/wxPython-src-3.0.2.0/src/osx/carbon/dcclient.cpp(195) in wxPaintDCImpl(): using wxPaintDC without being in a native paint event
```

self.staticBitmap is a wxStaticBitmap, and self.wxBitmap is the same exact image. My guess is it has something to do with a GraphicsContext, perhaps? There was a similar question asked here: [How to send PaintEvent in wxpython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25848249/how-to-send-paintevent-in-wxpython) but this did not help me. I did what they suggested with self.Refresh() but I have the same error coming up. Why would this be working on Windows but not on Mac? No drawing seems to be occurring on the image.

Comment: You may want to cross-post this to the https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/wxpython-users group or possibly https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/wxpython-mac

Comment: thanks, posted over there as well :)

Answer (score 2):

First, you shouldn't be handling the paint event for a native widget.  Sometimes it will work, like this case on Win7, but other times it won't, and it is not officialy supported by wxWidgets.  (The behavior is "undefined")

Second, why bother painting the `wx.StaticBitmap` at all?  If you need to change the bitmap that the widget is displaying you can just give it a new one with its `SetBitmap` method.  In this case if the grid you are drawing is dynamic (needs to change over time) then you could use a `wx.MemoryDC` to make a new bitmap with the grid (IOW, draw the bitmap and call `drawGrid` on the memory DC) and then pass that new bitmap to `SetBitmap`.

Third, you don't usually see calls to `event.Skip` in paint event handlers.  There may be cases where this could cause problems too, unless the base classes are expecting it.

Forth, it's not really a problem but using `wx.BufferedPaintDC` on Mac is superfluous as the platform is already double-buffering everything.  GTK does so in most cases as well.  There is a `wx.AutoBufferedPaintDC` that will either be a `PaintDC` or a `BufferedPaintDC` depending on if buffering is needed or not for the given platform.  Or you can decide which to use in your own code by looking at the return value of `window.IsDoubleBuffered()`.

Finally, if you would rather handle this problem using paint events instead of generating and swapping images in the `wx.StaticBitmap` then another approach you could take is to make a custom class similar to `wx.StaticBitmap` that simply paints a bitmap on itself, but also knows how to manage drawing the grid when it is needed, then you could use that class in place of the `wx.StaticBitmap`.  You could use the `wx.lib.statbmp` module as a starting point.

Comment: Thank  you. I suppose the intern before me went about the paint event the hard way, and I'll just have to re-write those portions of code. So the widget should be able to handle the paint events on its own and I don't even need the OnPaint() method anymore, just load the bitmap, create a MemoryDC, then call drawGrid() pretty much?